# SQlite3 - Delete row by rowid

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm currently building a small web app with Flask and I'm using SQLite3 as database. I want to implement a feature to delete rows in the database. To do that I have to select/delete the row by the standard rowid that SQLite3 is giving every row, but I don't know how to do that.

I know you can get the rowid of a row by:

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM table;
```

but I don't know how to reverse that.

Comment: Why do you need to SELECT the row first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to delete a row by its `rowid`, it is very straight forward, e.g.

```
  delete from mytable where rowid=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I tried it almost like this. I wrote "DELETE rowid, FROM  test WHERE rowid = 1" .